# Toree Installation Issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, pip, apache-toree

I wanted to pip install Toree package, but I ended up with the following error msg:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement toree (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for toree

I couldn't find any documentation on requirements for toree. Also, pip doesn't seem to be the issue here either since it successfully installed other packages I tested.

Here are my systems: 
1. Mac 10.11.16 
2. Pip 9.0.1 
3. Python 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toree is still in development version, so it's not currently located in the pypi. You will have to install it like this:

```
pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0/snapshots/dev1/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz
jupyter toree install
```

You can see this page for more details
https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

When pip says something like this, it means that it doesn't find toree at all: it may not have the module. The module can be installed once you download a package which can be taken from this link:

http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

my situation is similier to you,your jupyter client version is higher than the toree can find,try uninstalled jupyter client before.